# Force Magic: Why No Light Side Equivalent?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Is there ever a in or out-of universe explanation of why the truly impressive magic is left entirely to the Sith?

Particularly outside of the movies the Jedi do have access to a pretty decent range of abilities, but nothing like the stuff of advanced Sith sorcery. Much of it is of a kind a Jedi would, at the very very least, be less likely to use.

It would seem reasonable that a Jedi would be expected not to want to become immortal, or become a god. But even among the techniques that the Sith have developed, there are ones that fit within the Jedi philosophy (like advanced healing).

Is there any reason why a Jedi could not use the lightside to heal someone/bring them back to life just like Darth Plagueis does (or develop their own sorcery)?

Comment: A Jedi lives in harmony with the force. A Sith bends it to their will.

Comment: When somebody dies, they join the Force. Bringing somebody back from the dead seems like it would be going against the flow of the Force, does it not?

Comment: Repeated use of the terms "magic" and "sorcery" in a Star Wars question makes my head hurt.

Comment: It's a good point though. Even stuff like Sith lightning the Jedi don't have a counter for other then to hold their light saber out and absorb it, unless your yoda of course who can absorb it with his paw, lol. It does seem that from a distance the sith have a lot more at their disposal, except for yoda who can literally turn a light saber off and yank it out of a lesser opponents hand. +1

Comment: something something about jedi never using their powers for attack, only to protect others.

Comment: The Sith are willing to experiment with the Force. The Jedi are too afraid of turning to the dark side (even though quite a few of them do it anyway).

Comment: Mostly good stuff. There are many accounts of Jedi using impressive force powers for various reasons including harming enemies, healing and helping others, and more. I'll attempt to make a real answer out of it.

Comment: @DavidS The Star Wars EU introduced subsets and variations of the Force that were explicitly called magic and sorcery.  It doesn't necessarily refer to the Force as seen in the movies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what you mean by magic, though in [Dawn of The Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Jedi:_Into_the_Void) 
a character heals a large, rather fatal, hole in her belly using the force and a chunk of living flesh she has. This was before the whole Jedi and Sith deal though, so it's hard to say if this was sith like or Jedi like.
[Battle meditation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_meditation) is a notable power the Jedi use that always impresses me, which is used on numerous occasions. 
Jedi can in fact [heal wounds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_healing) and Jedi healers are not uncommon.

I won't reference any video games, as they give Jedi many powers, but Jedi philosophy seems to allow peaceful or 'good' uses of the force, both in and out of combat. I believe that as long as the powers are not solely for killing others, the code does not prevent them.

The Sith have always had notable and impressive force powers that specialize in strength, death and deception, but Jedi aim more for restoration, peace and counters to Sith powers. Though by no means do I mean that a Jedi cannot use destructive powers, it's just frowned upon.

As for resurrecting, the Jedi would most likely outlaw. As @Theik pointed out, it is sort of going against the flow of the force.

You ask many question, but there are numerous soft counters a Jedi can use against Sith powers, though a Jedi would never use something on the level of the [thought bomb](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thought_bomb) as it against the will of the force. Sith don't seem to mind committing atrocities against the force, though a Jedi never would.

I hope one of my examples of Jedi force powers and explanations answered your numerous questions.

Comment: In the [larger](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Shadow_Generator) [picture](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star) of [things](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Forge), it's ironic but the power of the force is insignificant next to the power of engineering.

Comment: @Axelrod I'd disagree. Humans are not afraid of crossing the line to destroy their enemies, but Jedi are. The Sith of old were capable of eating the life force of entire planets in a blink of an eye and could transcend mortality and their physical selves. Science can be impressive, but the limits of the Force, IMO, are far greater.

Answer (score 1):

Legacy canon answer:

In addition to the already mentioned answers, there was outright [magic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Magic) fueled by the lightside in the *Star Wars* galaxy.

It was used by the [non-Nightsister witches of Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dathomir_Magic):

> There were two schools of Dathomir Magic. The first, traditional Allyan Magic, followed rules put forth in the Book of Law, a tome of moral and ethical teachings kept and modified by each clan based on an original created by Allya for her daughters

Comment: Ok, sources added.